# 2 components almost identical to each other. The only difference is that each component has a different GET request. Merge them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently have 2 components which are almost identical to each other. HTML structure and CSS rules are the same and the only difference is that on `mounted()` of these components, a different GET request is made. One gets all the visited places and one gets all wishlisted place. The response to both GET request has the same structure, it just returns different places based on what the user has visited or wishlisted.

So my question is, am I meant to merge these 2 components into 1 component? If I were to do that, how would I determine whether I need to make the GET request for visited places or wishlisted places? Maybe based on the URL? If the URL is `http://localhost:8080/#/Admin/visited` execute the GET request which gets all visited places and if it's `http://localhost:8080/#/Admin/wishlist` get the wishlisted places?

Also what name would be appropriate for this component since it'll be used to get both visited places and wishlisted places? Also what would be an appropriate name for the data property which will replace `wishlist` and `visited`?

Wishlist.vue

```
<template>
    <div class='wishlisted-sights-list'>
        <div @click='selectSight(index)' class='wishlisted-sight' v-if='wishlist != null' v-for='(wishlistedPlace, index) in wishlist'>
            <img class='wishlisted-sight-photos' :src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=300&photoreference=' + wishlistedPlace.result.photos[0].photo_reference + '&key='">
            <div class="">
                <p class='wishlisted-sights-name'>{{ wishlistedPlace.result.name }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                wishlist: null,
                username: this.$route.params.username,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            selectSight(index) {
                const placeId = this.wishlist[index].result.place_id;
                this.$router.push('/' + this.username + '/' + placeId)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/getWishlist/' + this.username)
            .then(response => {
                this.wishlist = response.data.wishlistedPlaces
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Visited.vue

```
<template>
    <div class='visited-sights-list'>
        <div @click='selectSight(index)' class='visited-sight' v-if='visited != null' v-for='(visitedPlace, index) in visited'>
            <img class='visited-sight-photos' :src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=300&photoreference=' + visitedPlace.result.photos[0].photo_reference + '&key='">
            <div class="">
                <p class='visited-sights-name'>{{ visitedPlace.result.name }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                visited: null,
                username: this.$route.params.username,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            selectSight(index) {
                const placeId = this.visited[index].result.place_id;
                this.$router.push('/' + this.username + '/' + placeId)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/getVisited/' + this.username)
            .then(response => {
                this.visited = response.data.visitedPlaces
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Even though you declare the returned structure is the same, it's clearly not. One holds the `places` in `visitedPlaces` and one in `wishlistPlaces`. You can ***a)*** change the BE to always return the same prop (i.e. `places`) or ***b)*** have a mapper and map based on the `source` type. And your FE code needs refactoring to use the neutral prop (probably `places`).

Comment: I may have not expressed myself correctly. By "the returned structure is the same" I mean that the results from the GET request have the same properties structure. The different GET requests do return different places though.

Comment: Return `places` in both cases and change your FE component to use `places` regardless of whether they're visited or wishlist. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should make a reusable component, probably called `Places.vue`. However, your returned result should have the same structure (you have to rename `wishlistPlaces` and `visitedPlaces` to `places`, probably. Or `sights`):

Your component should take in the source parameter, along these lines:

```
<places source="getWishlist" />
```

And map it as:

```
props: {
  source: {
     type: String,
     required: true
  }
}
```

while your getter should something like:

```js
mounted() {
    axios.get(`/${this.source}/${this.userName}`)
    .then(response => {
        this.places = response.data.places
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

You obviously need to refactor all places where you now use `wishlist` or `visited` props/methods to use `places` (or `sights`, if that's your choice).

Comment: Where can I find what does source="getWishlist" do in the documentation? Sadly the answer is not making too much sense to me right now because of that.

Comment: [Here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html). It's a `prop`. You can pass it in directly as a string `<whatever source="getWishlist" />` or as a JavaScript expression `<whatever :source="\`getWishlist\`" />` (or any other JavaScript expression resulting in your desired string). Inside the component, I used it inside `mounted()` as `this.source` in `axios.get(\`/${this.source}/${this.userName}\`)`

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I think this will work out just fine.

Comment: Also it doesn't have to be called source right? It can be whatever I want?

Comment: Yes, you can call it whatever you want. If it's a multi term. like "this is my funky param" you should use kebabCase for the attribute: `<whatever this-is-my-funky-param="a string" />` and use camelcase in `props`: `thisIsMyFunkyParam: { ...}`. It's possible to use kebabCase in props, if you pass the key as a string: `'this-is-my-funky-param': {...}`, but you don't really want to use it as `this['this-is-my-funky-param']` inside your vm, do you?

Comment: You're welcome. The important thing to remember is: if the param is prefixed with a colon: `<whatever :my-prop="something" />`, `something` will be parsed as a JavaScript expression. If you want to pass in the `'something'` string, you can omit the colon.

Answer (score 2):

Separate getting the data from displaying the data. The parent can then perform both requests in its `mounted/created` hook and pass them as a prop to the display component:

```
<places :places="visited"/>
<places :places="whishlist"/>
```

Comment: You seem to have overlooked the fact the two responses have different structure. That needs to be refactored, too.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu quote from the original question "The response to both GET request has the same structure" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dynamic `<components>` it's good for cases where you have tabs so they are both loaded on creation (or mount) and then you give the props according to the needs. See here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html